# How do you setup an SSH connection from Ubuntu 12.04 to Amazon EC2

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I have been over countless Tutorials all that seem to be outdated...

X.509 certificates, keys / pairs blah blah...

I need a serious step by step how to create a connection from my local machine to the amazon EC2 can someone help me please.

I would rather a step by step then a link to a tutorial i think ive read and got no where with enough of those for today

Is there a simple setup like similar to github even?

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: Do you know how to create an ssh key on your local Ubuntu machine using ssh-keygen?

Comment: What Linux distro or AMI are you running?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using your default ssh key instead of having Amazon generate a completely different one for you (which many tutorials advise).

1. Create an ssh key for your local user.  If you already have one, skip this step

   test -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa || ssh-keygen
2. Upload your public ssh key to EC2, giving it a keypair name the same as your username:

   for region in $(ec2-describe-regions | cut -f2); do
     echo $region
     ec2-import-keypair --region $region \
       --public-key-file $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $USER
   done
3. Run an instance, passing in the name of the keypair you uploaded.  The example here uses the latest version of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise:

   ec2-run-instances --key $USER ami-82fa58eb
4. Wait for the instance to move to the "running" state and find the public IP address:

   ec2-describe-instances
5. Connect to the instance using your default ssh key.  The exact username depends on the AMI you are running and may be one of:

   ssh ubuntu@
   ssh ec2-user@
   ssh root@

Here's an article I wrote on uploading your personal ssh key instead of having Amazon generate them: http://alestic.com/2010/10/ec2-ssh-keys

Here's an article I wrote on the difference between all of the different AWS credentials: http://alestic.com/2009/11/ec2-credentials